# automatic page refresh without reload of entrie page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

refreshing a top bar just like facebook where the no of messages are getting updated when the new messages comes just like facebook or gmail without refreshing the whole page . i can do this if that top bar is located externally i can refresh that bar with either meta tag set timeout or with refresh tag , but not getting how to refresh when it is part of main page.how to do this without reloading whole page and without any external file as the full code of the inbox and alert is located in main.php so i cant take it out and call these function externally.

Comment: What you need is AJAX - if you have any **specific** question, feel free to ask.

Comment: @shadow , i know with ajax we can do but as i told i dont want to put any url as external url in ajax i have to give some url:xyz.php but i want to perform ajax internally without calling any external file

Comment: @Sujit sorry but I have no idea what you mean. If you can explain better it might help..

Comment: @shadow in my main page everything is there so if i ll refresh page it will show new message but if have to use ajax call then i have to place these codes in external file and i have to call these external file every 10 seconds so please tell how to make ajax call from the main php file only without placing these codes in some external file

Comment: @Sujit no you don't have to place the codes in external files. All the code can be in the same file.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try to set a timer to pick new messages with ajax method and use js to change dom element's performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a partial page refresh using an AJAX callback.  A good place to start learning AJAX is the [Google Code University](http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html) and the [jQuery JavaScript framework](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but try this one: http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2009/02/26/jquery-auto-refresh-div-every-x-seconds/

Comment: @user754471  in your example also one external file called response.php is there . i know with external file it can be done , please tell if you how to cal ajax internally without any external files.

Answer (score 0):

What about this then

```
setInterval(function(){
SomeAjaxFunction();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sujit, you definetly need to use AJAX. I think you have not explained yourself very clearly, but you are saying you want all the code on the same page, that's a bad programming practice. You need to use AJAX and have "code separation" (separate HTML from JS from PHP).

Maybe you are afraid of using AJAX, I recommend and easy library for managing AJAX, it's called [SACK](http://www.twilightuniverse.com/?page_id=243). You can see a nice an easy tutorial [here](http://www.sean-barton.co.uk/2008/09/sack-of-ajax/).

Hope that works for you.

Comment: i have seperated js css and allother file separately but for making ajax call i dont want to put my codes externally . my main page is having those codes which shows that new messages has come but i have to relod to see that so i wantt o use ajax but without compromising my speed and all . if my main page can tell that new message has come then why not ajax can call the main.php and tell that new message has come or not. i am very sure it can be done . i am working on that.